# react photoswipe gallery of thumbnails will not display as grid

Tags: css, reactjs, photoswipe

I'm using photoswipe gallery.

When I do so, I get all the thumbnails in a single line... I would like them to fill the page like a grid.

[image: All thumbnails in single vertical row]

Below is my react component code.  I have noticed that if I go to each thumbnail in dev tools->inspect and change display to 'inline' I don't end up with a line break after/before each.  It still looks garbage because lack of frames and other things, However, I don't know how or where to modify the look or styling of the thumbnails put that in my code.

import { PhotoSwipeGallery } from 'react-photoswipe-2';

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    loadingPaper: {
        margin: "auto",
        width: '50%',
        padding: '10px',
        marginTop: "50px"
    }
}));


function FrameViewer(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let { cameraAccessor } = useParams();
    const [frames, setFrames] = useState([]);
    const [isGalleryOpen, setIsGalleryOpen] = useState(false);
    const [imgGalleryH, setGalleryImgH] = useState(0);
    const [imgGalleryW, setGalleryImgW] = useState(0);
    const [cameraID, setCameraID] = useState("");
    const { cameras } = props;


    async function fetchCameraData(cameraAccessor) { // TODO: check if already loading before running.  // code to get filenames and what not
    }

    useEffect(() => {
// code to lead camera data
    }, [cameraAccessor]);

    const getThumbnailContent = item => (
        <img src={item.thumbnail} width={120} height={90} alt="" />
    );

    let cam = cameras[cameraID];

    if (cam) { // Photoswipe requires a Height and Width ... so we need to load the first image and see how big before we can incept Photoswipe.

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            setGalleryImgH(img.height);
            setGalleryImgW(img.width);
        }
        img.src = "https://apps.usgs.gov/sstl/media/cameras/" + cameraFolderName(cam) + "/" + cameraFolderName(cam) + MOST_RECENT_FRAME_SUFFIX;
    }



    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {cam && frames && frames.length && imgGalleryH > 0 && imgGalleryW > 0
                ? <PhotoSwipeGallery

                    items={frames.map((filename) => {
                        return {
                            src: 'https://example.com/media/cameras/' + cameraFolderName(cam) + '/' + filename,
                            thumbnail: 'https://example.com/media/cameras/' + cameraFolderName(cam) + '/' + filename,
                            w: imgGalleryW,
                            h: imgGalleryH,
                            title: filename.replace("_overlay.jpg", "").split("___")[1].replace("_", " ")
                        }
                    })}
                    options={{
                        closeOnScroll: false
                    }}
                    thumbnailContent={getThumbnailContent}
                    isOpen={isGalleryOpen}
                    onClose={() => setIsGalleryOpen(false)}
                />
                : <Paper elevation={5} className={classes.loadingPaper}><Typography color="textSecondary" align='center'>loading...</Typography></Paper>
            }
        </React.Fragment >
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your CSS. Try overriding the **display** property at the container level (.pswp-thumbnails):

```
.pswp-thumbnails
{
  display: flex;
}
```

... **OR** at the thumbnail level (.pswp-thumbnail):

```
.pswp-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
}
```